# How to disable right click in youtube video running in my website page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

disable the right click in object tag how to possible

```
<object id="tlClogo" class="tlClogo" data="url" width="80%" height="315"></object>
```

Comment: Why bother? Whatever you're trying to prevent can be circumvented by *Inspect Element* or similar...

Comment: Have you done any research and/or tried anything? Either way, I agree with @CD001

Comment: document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: there is only HTML here, no php or jquery or javascript which makes the question unclear

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you cannot, because that's an iframe from YouTube, which you don't have control to edit.

You can try to overlap the player with an invisible element (e.g. opacity: `0.001`), which would block the right click, but also the other events. Note this way you would break the Google rules regarding that embedded player.

Comment: you can follow this trick. It is possible : https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/issues/2444